# Getting an error message while changing hats

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2013

I have earned a few hats, and I went to set one. Worked fine the first time, but I got the positioning way off, so I went back in to change it, and got this:

[image: Image of an error while changing hats.]

> An error occurred while changing the hat - please try again.

I was able to hit the remove all hats button to clear the bad positioning, but it won't let me set a hat any more. I've even switched sites from Arqade to here, and tried again, and it's still erroring out.

This is in Windows 7, Internet Explorer 10, fully updated, with no plugins/addons.

Comment: Browser & system spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're looking at the site at a non-100% zoom level. In that case, IE reports fractional mouse cursor coordinates, while we were expecting integer ones. Fixed now.